# Using variables for colors in table cells

Tags: colors, cell, mediawiki

Using the variables extension, I want to change the background color of a cell in a table. So far I've done this:

```
{{#vardefine:green|<span style="background:Green; color:White">text</span>}}
```

The problem is that, when I add {{#var:green}} to the cell, only the text itself has a green background. Ideally, I want the whole cell to have a background color, like it does if I use this:

```
| bgcolor="#ff00ff" | test
```

or this

```
| style="background:silver" |silver
```

in the cell.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided on the [mwusers forum](http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?14572-Using-variables-for-colors-in-table-cells&p=48370#post48370).

Essentially I need to:

1. Create Template:! - which contains only | (see it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:!))
2. Define the variables, e.g.:

   {{#vardefine: sample1 | bgcolor=green{{!}}Test}}
3. Enter this in a cell:

   {{#var:sample1}}

Comment: Please see also this wiki Q&A forum in start up phase: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wiki-edit

Answer (score 0):

That's simply not going to work.  I presume your table row looks like this:

```
 | Not in span {{#var:green|Text}}
```

That means you're defining a span *within* the cell, not defining the color of the cell itself.

```
 | Not in span <span style="background:Green; color:White">Text</span>
```

Cell styles have to go before the content:

```
 | bgcolor="green" | Now it's all green
```

Instead, why not tag the row with a CSS class called 'green' and then define that in your Wiki CSS?  See [Help:Table#Style classes](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Table#Style_classes).

Comment: I assume you mean in "MediaWiki:Common.css"  I'd rather not because that is a global page that affects every user.  My assumption is that it will (if I add enough of these things) slow down wiki response.  Is that correct?

Comment: Quite the contrary, CSS styling is probably much faster than custom variable processing and the overhead of an additional span in every cell.